# Using Kaniko cache with Google Cloud Build for Google Cloud Kubernetes Deployments

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build, kaniko

We have been using Google Cloud Build via build triggers for our GitHub repository which holds a C++ application that is deployed via Google Cloud Kubernetes Cluster.

[image]

As seen above, our build configuration is arriving from Dockerfile which is located in our GitHub repository.

Everything is working as expected, however our builds lasts about 55+ minutes. I would like to add Kaniko Cache support as suggested [here], however Google Cloud document only suggests a way to add it via a yaml file as below :

```
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/kaniko-project/executor:latest'
  args:
  - --destination=gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/image
  - --cache=true
  - --cache-ttl=XXh
```

How shall I achieve Kaniko builds with a Dockerfile based trigger ?

```
FROM --platform=amd64 ubuntu:22.10
ENV GCSFUSE_REPO gcsfuse-stretch

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install --yes --no-install-recommends \
    ca-certificates \
    curl \
    gnupg \
  && echo "deb http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt $GCSFUSE_REPO main" \
    | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/gcsfuse.list \
  && curl https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | apt-key add - \
  && apt-get update \
  && apt-get install --yes gcsfuse \
  && apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/* 

EXPOSE 80

RUN \
  sed -i 's/# \(.*multiverse$\)/\1/g' /etc/apt/sources.list && \
  apt-get update && \
  apt-get -y upgrade && \
  apt-get install -y build-essential && \
  apt-get install -y gcc && \
  apt-get install -y software-properties-common && \
  apt install -y cmake && \
  apt-get install -y make && \
  apt-get install -y clang && \
  apt-get install -y mesa-common-dev && \
  apt-get install -y git && \
  apt-get install -y xorg-dev && \
  apt-get install -y nasm && \
  apt-get install -y byobu curl git htop man unzip vim wget && \
  rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* 

# Update and upgrade repo
RUN apt-get update -y -q && apt-get upgrade -y -q 

COPY . /app
RUN cd /app
RUN ls -la

# Set environment variables.
ENV HOME /root
ENV WDIR /app

# Define working directory.
WORKDIR /app

RUN cd /app/lib/glfw && cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" && make && apt-get install libx11-dev
RUN apt-cache policy libxrandr-dev
RUN apt install libxrandr-dev

RUN cd /app/lib/ffmpeg && ./configure && make && make install
RUN cmake . && make

# Define default command.
CMD ["bash"]
```

Any suggestions are quite welcome.

Comment: it looks like you can add only kaniko in a yaml file as its also the only options in this [github link](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/kaniko#running-kaniko-in-google-cloud-build) but you can add the --dockerfile agument to find your Dockerfile path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comment, You can only add your kaniko in your `cloudbuild.yaml` files as its also the only options shown in this [github link](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/kaniko#running-kaniko-in-google-cloud-build) but you can add the `--dockerfile` argument to find your Dockerfile path.